# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "dicht" und "wasserdicht"?

Tags: difference

Alles steht im Titel. Was ist der Unterschied zwischen

- **dicht**, in zum Beispiel:

> Es kann dicht verschließen.

- Und **wasserdicht**, in zum Beispiel:

> Es ist wasserdicht bis 10 Meter.

Ich glaube, dass es in beiden Fällen bedeutet, dass kein Wasser fließen kann. Was ist also der Unterschied?

EDIT : Danke für ihre Antworten. Ich dachte an eine Uhr : wir sagen, dass es wasserdicht bis .. m ist, aber können wir sagen, dass das Uhrengehäuse dicht ist ? (Ich möchte sagen, dass das Wasser nicht in die Box passen kann). Warum ? Die Bedeutung ist nahe.

Comment: Diese Frage lässt sich ohne Kenntnis des Kontexts nicht beantworten. Von was redest du? Was ist dicht oder wasserdicht? Eine Uhr? Eine Flasche? Ein U-Boot? Ein Gartenschlauch? Ein Wärmedämmverbundsystem? Ein Multifunktionsfensterdichtband? Bitte spezifiziere.

Comment: Wenn es um Produktbeschreibungen geht, haben die beiden Worte Bedeutungen, die spezieller sind als der allgemeine Sprachgebrauch - geht es um eine Produktbeschreibung? Ansonsten gibt es z.B. auch Anwendungen bei denen nur eines der beiden Wörter richtig ist : 'wasserdichtes Alibi', oder 'Sie standen dicht beieinander'

Comment: Och, da gibt's noch mehr: Er war so dicht, dass es dicht an einer Vergiftung war.

Comment: *Wasserdicht bis xxx m* bedeutet auch, dass die Dichtung einen gewissen Druck aushält. Etwas kann allerdings nicht nur Wasserdicht, sondern auch z.B. staubdicht oder luftdicht sein. Eine Grenze, ein Tor oder eine Tür können auch dicht sein und trotzdem wasser-, staub- und luftdurchlässig.

Comment: Die genaue Bedeutung von "dicht" ist sehr abhängig vom Kontext.

Answer (score 4):

Das ist eine Fehlannahme. *Dicht* kann auch lediglich *staubdicht* heißen. Für Wasserdichtigkeit gibt es verschiedene Angaben. Armbanduhren werden beispielsweise mit der Angabe *Wasserdicht bis … m* beworben, bei Elektroartikeln gibt es die [Schutzart.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzart)

Comment: Dicht könnte auch *luftdicht* bedeuten.

Comment: Gestern war die Autobahn dicht.... der Regen lief trotzdem ab. Zum Glück.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen das nicht blickdichte Negligé.

Answer (score 2):

Die Zusammensetzung »wasserdicht« ist ein auf Wasser bezogener Spezialfall von »dicht« in der Bedeutung »undurchlässig, undurchdringlich«. Die Aussage, dass etwas (bzgl. dieser Bedeutung) dicht sei, bezieht sich gemeinhin auf einen von sechs Fällen.

> **(1)** etwas dringt nicht von außen nach innen
>
> **(2)** etwas dringt nicht von innen nach außen

wobei »etwas«

> **(a)** Flüssigkeit
>
> **(b)** Gas
>
> **(c)** Festkörper

sein kann.

*Beispiele*

> **(1a)** dichte Taucheruhr, dichter Trockenanzug (Wasser dringt nicht nach
> innen)
>
> **(1b)** dichte Vakuumröhre (Luft dringt nicht nach innen)
>
> **(1c)** dichte Imkerhaube (Bienen dringen nicht nach innen), dichter
> Zeckenschutzanzug (Zecken dringen nicht nach innen)
>
> **(2a)** dichte Wasserleitung, Öl-Pipeline (Wasser bzw. Öl dringt nicht
> nach außen), dichtes Kondom (Sperma dringt nicht nach außen)
>
> **(2b)** dichte Schwimmflügel, Luftmatratzen, Luftballons, dichtes
> Schlauchboot (Luft dringt nicht nach außen)
>
> **(2c)** dichte Sanduhr (Sand dringt nicht nach außen), dichtes
> Kirschkernkissen (Kirschkerne dringen nicht nach außen)

Comment: Nach verbreitetem (laxem) Sprachgebrauch können auch ein Alibi oder eine Argumentation wasserdicht sein. Das ist natürlich metaphorisch zu verstehen. *Wasser* ist hier mehr ein Suffix zur Verstärkung von *dicht*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Kann ich bestätigen, ich beziehe mich lediglich auf die in der Frage genannte Bedeutung.